# Ionic AngularJS http on service do not update controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, promise

This probably because I'm not sure how to use promise, but after I call the service, which trigger http call, in my controller the result is empty array.. why is that?
I have my app setup like this:

This is app.js

```
//App.js
  .state('myApp.sermonlists', {
    url: "/sermonlists",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/sermonlists.html",
        controller: 'SermonListsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

This is controller.js

```
//controller.js
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('SermonListsCtrl', function($scope, sermonListsService) {
  // call sermon api
  sermonListsService.getSermonLists(); // this return empty array()
})
```

This is services.js

```
//services.js
angular.module('myApp.services', [])

.factory('sermonListsService', function($http) {
    var sermon = [];

    function sermonJson() {
        $http.get('http://myapicall.com').then(function(resp) {
          // For JSON responses, resp.data contains the result
          sermon = resp.data;
         }, function(err) {
          console.error('ERR', err);
          // err.status will contain the status code
        })          
    }

    // initializing sermonJson call
    function init() {
        sermonJson();
    }

    // run init()
    init();

    return {
        getSermonLists: function(){

            return sermon;
        },
        getUser: function(index){
            return "";
        }
    }
})
```

What is the best practice for this? it will be great if you can help me fix this, and also example

Comment: use [`ng-resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 0):

You have created different modules for controller and services, hence they are not getting injected. To inject them, you have either manage it's dependansy or you may need to make module same

Try below

```
//controller.js
angular.module('myApp', [])
     .controller('SermonListsCtrl', function($scope, sermonListsService) {
     // call sermon api
      sermonListsService.getSermonLists(); // this return empty array()
});


//services.js
 angular.module('myApp', [])

 .factory('sermonListsService', function($http) {
   var sermon = [];

    function sermonJson() {
    $http.get('http://myapicall.com').then(function(resp) {
      // For JSON responses, resp.data contains the result
      sermon = resp.data;
     }, function(err) {
      console.error('ERR', err);
      // err.status will contain the status code
    })          
}

// initializing sermonJson call
function init() {
    sermonJson();
}

// run init()
init();

return {
    getSermonLists: function(){

        return sermon;
    },
     getUser: function(index){
        return "";
     }
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that getSermonLists() returns a reference to the empty array (initially this is ok), but $http callback does not fill the array but only replaces the internal list. The return value of getSermonLists() still references the empty array, even if "var sermon" in the service now references the filled array.

#### Use same array instance

First you could change the $http callback to take all elements of the response and push them to the array instead of just changing the reference. I.e.:

```
$http.get(...).then(function(response) {
    // Add all elements of response.data to sermon, you could also use a loop here
    sermom.push.apply(sermon, response.data)
});
```

This would also change the controllers list, because the list is still the same instance.

#### Using promise

Second way would be to use promises, as you already suggested. In this case `getSermonLists` shouldn't return an array but a promise, which is in an unresolved state, until the ajax call is finished. Angular uses the `$q` service to create promises:

```
var sermon = $q.defer();
function sermonJson() {
    sermon = $http.get(....).then(function(response) {
        sermon.resolve(response.data);
    });
}

getSermonList: function() {
    return sermon;
}
```

And change your controller to use the promise:

```
sermonListsService.getSermonLists().then(function(sermonList) {
    // Do something with sermonList, e.g. $scope.sermons = sermonList;
});
```

Promises would allow the controller to wait for the sermons to be loaded and do something afterwards, and it can handle the case of failed request.

Comment: why you redefine `sermon`? first `var sermon = $q.defer();` second `sermon = $http.get(....)`?

Comment: @Grundy would you mind writing a solution for this with best practice of ionic/angularjs style. Thanks